# add elements to WPF Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, image, grid

I wanted to make a function that populates a Grid in WPF with pictures. So I did that:

```
private void setCellImage(Grid g, Image img, int column, int row)
{

    Grid.SetColumn(img, column);
    Grid.SetRow(img, row);

    if (!g.Children.Contains(img))
        g.Children.Add(img);

    g.UpdateLayout();
}
```

And was using it by calling in that way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<15; j++)
        setCellImage(gameMap,background, i, j);
```

But it wasn't working. it populated a grid only in cell 14,14 leaving all other cells blank.

I thought that it may be my  mistake that I should use another instances of Image but it wasn't that:

```
private  void setCellImage(Grid g, Image img, int column, int row)
{
    Image _img = new Image();
    _img = img;

    Grid.SetColumn(_img, column);
    Grid.SetRow(_img, row);

    if (!g.Children.Contains(_img))
        g.Children.Add(_img);

    g.UpdateLayout();
}
```

This thing is still not working.

Comment: Just a thought, even in code below new instance of Image was not used. In second line "_img = img;", after this statement has been executed _img will contain reference of object referred by reference img.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is the value of the background variable set? If it is not going to change in your loop then you're just displacing the same image here and there

Comment: Both of you were right. I made modifications and it is now working just great. Thank you!